# Accesing all keys from json whose type is java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, json, gson

I have written a method which tells the type of JSON.
Code:

```
jsonObject.getClass().getName();
```

which returns `java.util.ArrayList []` or it can be `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap { }`

Now I want to retrieve all the keys from a json whose type is `ArrayList`. Here I want to pass input as jsonobject whose type is arrayList.

Here is sample JSON which I am using -

```
[{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "suni1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}]
```

So now I want to retrieve keys like widget, style, size, text, image etc. Like outerkeys as well as inner keys as well.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want to check for the existence of the certain keys in the received JSON or whether you need to access the value of the keys mentioned.

Comment: I have written one method, which tell the type of json it is. 
public static String GetObjectType(Object strName)
 {
 
  return jsonObject.getClass().getName();
 }
Now this gives the return type as java.util.ArrayList [] and now I want to access all keys of this json. I am using gson libraries.
@https://stackoverflow.com/users/3812888/the-head-rush

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ObjectMapper` from the Jackson library or `Gson` to iterate over your keys.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String s = "YOUR_JSON_HERE";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<Map<String, Object>> treeMap = mapper.readValue(s, List.class);
    //for Gson
    //Gson gson = new Gson();
    //List<Map<String, Object>> treeMap = gson.fromJson(s, List.class);

    List<String> keys  = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(treeMap.stream().map( t -> findAllKeys(t,keys)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}

private static List<String> findAllKeys(Map<String, Object> treeMap , List<String> keys) {
    treeMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
        if (value instanceof LinkedHashMap) {
            Map<String, Object> map = (LinkedHashMap) value;
            findAllKeys(map, keys);
        }
        keys.add(key);
    });

    return keys;
}
```

Comment: At very first,I have stored json data in simple java object and then by accessing this java object I am trying to find out what is the type of json object is.
public static Object jsonObject = null;
 
 public static Object GetJSONObject(String jsonFilePath) throws JsonSyntaxException, JsonIOException, FileNotFoundException
 {
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  jsonObject = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFilePath), Object.class);
  return jsonObject;
 }

The input I am giving to my method is
public static String[] GetAllKeyArrayNameOfArrayList(ArrayList<?> arrayList)

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: Nope, I want to pass json object which is in form of arraylist.

Comment: Can anyone help on this, I have stored a data plain object class and limitations are to use Object class and not to store data in String variable. Directly accessing data from console response.